# Codeigniter and Google maps Api V 3

Tags: codeigniter, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am looking for some advice from somebody who has used Google maps and Codeigniter. I am new to maps and working on a project that is built with Codeigniter and uses Google Maps. I am wondering whether to incorporate it directly into the project or use a library for it.

I have found a library here - http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library and have started using it and have found it easy to use for incorporating maps. I am wondering however if anyone else has used it and if so does it have the full functionality of Google Maps.

I know that Google Maps has amazing features and I am a bit anxious to continue with the library and discover later in my project that it doesn't support the functionality I might need.  I am going to keep researching it but if anyone has experience with it I would  appreciate some advice.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I've used two different Google Maps libraries for CodeIgniter 2.

I ended up keeping [the one you've linked](http://biostall.com/codeigniter-google-maps-v3-api-library) for both projects.  It was cleaner to use than the other, less helpers to load and lines to write in order to create a simple map.  I don't know what else you're really looking for here.  Also, with this library, I only needed to pass two variables into the View... where with the other, the View needed a bit more complex code.  Really, there's only two variables that need to be passed into the view... the Map and the JavaScript for the map.  If you're clever, you could also combine them into one.

**Quote OP:**

> *"I know that Google Maps has amazing features and I am a bit anxious to continue with the library and discover later in my project that it doesn't support the functionality I might need."*

So what?  If that's your only concern, then don't worry.  Switching out something like this is pretty easy.  Since it's invoked and configured in your Controller (or it should be), there's relatively little code to change.

*(The developer was also very responsive to my support requests, which is saying a lot for a open source project.)*

Comment: Thanks for you response. I have found the library very easy to use so far. I am building a project that will allow users to put markers on maps to represent services available at a venue - different colour markers for different services. These will then be stored in a database and retrieved and displayed on a map using a dropdown list. Because I have no experience with using maps I am just afraid that this might not be supported. I have already discovered that markers wont display on a map if `$config['places'] = TRUE;` is enabled.

Comment: @WicketW.Warwick, If you're not familiar with using the Google Map API in the first place, this is not going to be as easy for you no matter which library you choose.  The whole thing operates on JavaScript and this CI library only facilitates writing correct JavaScript code for you.  I suggest you create a static HTML version of this map first, so you understand exactly how to make it work, _before_ doing it within CodeIgniter.  Some of that Google Maps JavaScript is quirky... not quite as easy as jQuery.

Comment: Thanks again - I have found the library brilliant and straightforward to use so far. I have dynamically created 50 maps with a marker for the center point pulling lat long data from a database. I am just thinking that maybe there might be more support and tutorials for Google Maps over what's available for this library so if I get stuck it might be easier to find a solution. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: @WicketW.Warwick, Of course.  That's my point... use the Google API documentation for figuring out how to do it first.  This library is only a tool that writes the JavaScript for the former... he doesn't need to duplicate or even compete with Google's documentation.